# Lessa The Crimson Knight, weird cover page?

Tags: lessa-the-crimson-knight

So here is the cover page from **Lessa the Crimson Knight**.

[image]

*I don't think* I've ever seen this character, maybe it in the future,
but not once. Anyone know if he's from the first manga "Lessa", and I just missed him, or if I just forgot.

Comment: ... there faces look the same, but he has blue hair, and he doesn't have a sword **at least looking like that**

Answer (score 1):

That is

> Lessa, from the second season.

and (SPOILER ALERT!)

> he put on a red wig to disguise  himself. He explains about it in the second season.